# Apache 2.2 Mod Proxy ProxyPass behavior

Tags: apache, http, virtualhost, mod-proxy

I have a server `server.example.com` which serves Tomcat on port 80 via a `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` to 8080 and a Drupal site on the same box at `server.example.com:8001`.  If I enter in the port 8001 explicitly, the Drupal site behaves properly, but I need to make it accessible via `server.example.com/blog` so I created a `ProxyPass`/`ProxyPassReverse` for `/blog http://server.example.com:8001` which serves the initial page for the Drupal site correctly, but once the form on the home page of Drupal is filled out and submitted, which POSTs to `/`, the site changes to the Tomcat site, presumably because the / is not relative to the current host on post :8001.  How can I get the `ProxyPass` for `/blog` to remain persistent so that all subsequent requests remain within the `:8001 VirtualHost` (Drupal site)?

One thing I tried was with mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} /^blog/.*$
RewriteRule (.*) %{HTTP_HOST}:8001/$1 [L,P,NC]
```

But that did nothing at all as far as I can tell.  I was hoping that if the initial request was for /blog then the referrer would be as well and I could keep requests on the :8001 virtualhost.  Perhaps someone can explain why that is flawed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are very likely running into is that the documents returned by Drupal include generated links that all reference `/` instead of `/blog`.  `mod_rewrite` and `proxypass` don't do anything to the *contents* of documents -- they only act upon the *request* (or, in the case of ProxyPassReverse, on links such as Location: headers in returned content).

To make an application that normally expects to be installed as `/` operate on a different URL, you need either to :

(a) Configure the application to be aware of the proper base URL.  Many applications include such a setting in order to support exactly the situation you have described.

(b) Install some sort of filtering proxy that can modify the content of returned documents.  For Apache, [mod_proxy_html](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) is made to do exactly this.  This is included natively in Apache 2.4 but may need to be installed separately for 2.2.

Comment: That sounds very correct, in fact I have found the $base_url setting in the settings.php file which does the A) part, but I believe more needs to be done.  I am getting a white index.php page now, which makes me think includes are not being found.  I will most likely mark yours as accepted, but want to encourage some more answers first.  Thanks for your input, it is quite accurate I think.